# SQL a table for each metadata of other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, nosql, relational-database

Hi I have various time series each having a unique timeseries ID. Given an ID, the series look something like this (obviously with different dates and data respetively)

```
datetime    data
1/1/1980    11.6985
1/2/1980    43.6431
1/3/1980    54.9089
1/4/1980    63.1225
1/5/1980    72.4399
1/6/1980    79.1363
1/7/1980    82.2778
1/8/1980    86.0785
```

These time series have different "types". For instance, suppose that some time series are "WindData" type, some that are "SolarData" type and some that are "GasData" type. Given a timeseries ID, this will belong to some type. For instance:

- IDs 1, 2, 3 could belong to SolarData
- IDs 4,5 could belong to Wind Data
- ID 6 could belong to GasData.

Time series of the same type (for instanec 1, 2, 3) share the same fields of metadata (but not the same values!) For instance WindData could have fields:

- WindTurbineNumber, WindFarmName, Country

while the SolarData could have fields:

- SiteName, SolarPanelType

and the GasData could have:

- PipelineNumber, CountryOfOrigin, CountryOfDestination

Now, the issue is that as time grows I could have many many more types. Therefore, I want a way of generalizing this data-metadata structure. How? My idea would be to have:

- A table that given a timeseries id it tells me the type of that series (i.e. given 1, it tells SolarData)
- A table that given the type, it would give me the column names (and optionally their types)
- a table that given the id, it would return the data.

What database structure would I need?

I cannot figure out how I would create a table (or multiple tables) that could tell me, given a seriesid, which metadata fields it needs..

Comment: Why not a table for each kind of data?

Comment: I can't follow this. It just wanders all over the place. Can you post some actual details so we have an idea of what you need? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I added a nosql tag to the question because it might get more useful answers from people searching for that subject matter.

Comment: What about using a nvarchar column with JSON data?

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Honestly, I didn't even think of it because it took Microsoft so long to come to the JSON party, and I haven't done any production JSON work with SS2016+. Worth pursuing, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're not going to find a relational database structure that will really suit your needs here.

Relational databases are designed with a "schema on write" philosophy. We decide what the data we will be getting in the future will look like, then we design a storage structure with that data schema, and then insert data into that schema. Under the right circumstances, this works well, as evidenced by fifty or so years of Boyce-Codd-esque database structures.

It sounds, though, like you want to store your data as you receive it, whatever that shape may be, and then apply a "schema on read" philosophy, extracting the useful bits later, in the form the query requires. That's going to require a NoSQL or NewSQL solution. You could consider any number of appliances to accomplish that, from Hadoop and its related structures like HBase (but not Hive) to CouchDB or Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

The general ideal goes as below. You must a kind of series table and a "father" series table and some child series tables.

```
create table dbo.Seriekind
(
    Id int not null primrary key
   ,Description varchar(50) not null
   ,ListOfColumns varchar(500) not null
)

create table dbo.Series
(
   Id int not null indentity primary key
  ,TimeStamp datetime not null
  ,SerieKindId int not null
)

create table dbo.SolarData
(
     Id int not null primary key identity
    ,SerieId int not null
    ,SiteName
    ,SolarPanelType
)

create table dbo.WindData
(
     Id int not null primary key identity
    ,SerieId int not null
    ,WindTurbineNumber
    ,WindFarmName
    ,Country
)

create table dbo.GasData
(
     Id int not null primary key identity
    ,SerieId int not null
    ,PipelineNumber
    ,CountryOfOrigin
    ,CountryOfDestination
)
```

One "disvantage" you do needs a new table for any new kind of data. FK are trivial.

**Edit**

As Eric explained SQL structure is not that flexible. It's awesome to describe data relations and is really efficient in storing and fetching large chunks of data, not to say it's capabilities in some kinds of processing.

A better solution is maybe a a hybrid one, maybe storing the data as a flexible format like json inside a Series table or even do use a NoSql solution or a hybrid of SQL x NoSQL.

The main thing here is how many series do you need and how often a new one can come in. A dozen: SQl, A thousand: NoSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The thing is that in the future I will have loads of different kind of data, so I was looking for a more general way of doing this